# How to remove recent files from windows applications?

Tags: windows, windows-10, recent-items

Whenever I make secondary click on any windows application, it shows me a list of recent files:

[image]

I have already tried to remove them using this:

[image]

but they don't go away. Could you help me?

Comment: Did you restart the computer after clearing Quick Access?  If not, clear again, close out all, and restart. Then test again.

Comment: how do I remove quiack access? I only did what I posted, I restart the computer but they are still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actuallly these are called jump lists. You can go to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`,  `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations`,`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent` and remove the files there. Restart explorer then with `taskkill /im explorer.exe /f & explorer` in command prompt.

Comment: What happens if I remove all the files that are in %APPDATA%?, and what is the last taskkill command for?

Comment: No no no dont remove everything in `%Appdata%`, it contains many per-User valuable application data and preferences that is required for windows and other applications to work properly. We are only allowed to remove specific files in the `%Appdata%`. The last `taskkill` command will kill running explorer (the total windows shell), `/f` switch makes it forcefully. Then we restart explorer and windows shell with the command after ampersand. This is a good practice to notify system about the changes made.

Comment: if I restart the whole operating sytem, can avoid the last command?

Comment: Yes you can avoid the last command if you restart whole system. or you can call UpdatePerUserSystemParameters function from user32.dll, but that is advanced and not recommended. Better is you restart system or explorer.

Comment: well, I have already done what you told me, and now they don't appear, thanks

Comment: Welcome. If you have found the answer helpful, then please click the bog check mark in the answer to accept is the answer of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer somewhere and works easily no need to do all that.

"Click on Settings-Personalization-Start-Show Recently Opened Items In Jump Lists On Start Or The Taskbar (Uncheck and after Check)
It resets Start Menu Recent and The Photos Recent Files."

Was answered by: Nikolaos https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/91084c49-e40d-4404-9871-b9e196ed6c6c

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me. The files immediately disappeared from %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent as soon as this is unchecked.